# How should I unpack dict keys, values as columns, values in an embedded MySQL statement?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am building a lightweight POST handler in Python (2.7) that accepts a POST and inserts its contents into a MySQL database. Simple, I'm sure, but this is a first for me.

My limited knowledge of Python and its ways, has led me to using an **OrderedDict** to capture the POST's keys, values.  Now, for the part I don't understand...

How should I unpack these key, value pairs in the MySQL statement? Keys as Columns, Values as Values.

Here is my current attempt:

```
d = collections.OrderedDict([
                    ('key1', 'value1'),
                    ('key2', 'value2'),
                    ('key3', 'value3')])

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO entries %s '
                   'VALUES %s',
                   (d.keys(), d.values()))
```

Of course, this fails. The d.{func}() return a list. This is the result that I think I need:

```
d = collections.OrderedDict([
                    ('key1', 'value1'),
                    ('key2', 'value2'),
                    ('key3', 'value3')])

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO entries (key1, key2, key3) '
                   'VALUES (value1, value2, value3)'
```

I feel as though I missing something basic and obvious. What is it? :)

Comment: Firstly why are you using a dict at all here? Secondly, rather than reinventing the wheel, you should use one of the many existing web (micro) frameworks to handle your POST and db connection.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar. Recommend one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections

d = collections.OrderedDict(
    [
            ('key1', 'value1'),
            ('key2', 'value2'),
            ('key3', 'value3')
    ]
)

table_name = "entries"

sql_query = "INSERT INTO {} {} VALUES {}".format(table_name, str(tuple(d.keys())).replace("'", ""), str(tuple(d.values())).encode('utf-8'))
print sql_query
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO entries (key1, key2, key3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

Comment: This works! Except, after deploying... My app's log says: "You have an error in your SQL syntax".   The sql statement looks like this: `INSERT INTO entries (key1, key2, key3) VALUES (u'value1', u'value2', u'value3')`. 

What is the 'u' all about and how do I account for it?

Comment: @queuetheory I've updated my answer adding `encode('utf-8')`. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: That makes sense.  I forgot about utf-8.  The update didn't actually solve it, but I did find a solution by encoding my requests.  Does this look right? `OrderedDict([('key1', self.request.get('key1').encode('utf-8')),('key2', self.request.get('key2').encode('utf-8'))])`  It solves the syntax issue.

Comment: @queuetheory great! I'm glad my answer helped.